# Longer Google autocomplete lists?

Tags: google-search

Is it possible to have more items in the Google autocomplete suggestions as you type?

Answer (score 1):

Per default, Google gives you 4 autocomplete suggestions:[image: Screenshot showing Google displaying 4 autocomplete suggestions]

You can tweak your settings so that you'll get 10 suggestions. Go to Google search settings at https://www.google.com/preferences

For Google **Instant predictions** make sure **Never Show Instant Results** is ticked. Make sure to click the **save settings** button at the bottom of the page.

Now, try searching again. You should now get 10 suggestions:

[image: Screenshot showing Google displaying 10 autocomplete suggestions]