# How can I see more Google autocomplete suggestions?

Tags: google-search

Is there a way to view more than 10 (or customized) number of entries that Google auto-complete suggests?
Or a list of all suggestions Google auto-complete has identified related to the text in the search box?

For example, if I am searching for `Mathematical Model of`, I want Google to suggest for what all types of devices / systems mathematical models can be derived.

I have gone through [this: Longer Google autocomplete lists?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8990/longer-google-autocomplete-lists) article but that only allows 10 suggestions to be viewed.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, there is no way to get more than 10 autocomplete suggestions for Google searches.

As an alternative, you can create additional queries that are the same as your original query bug with a space and then a letter to get more, different autocomplete suggestions. i.e. `Mathematical Model of a`, `Mathematical Model of b`, etc. where `a` and `b` are other relevant terms that you're searching for.